# File access in Experience Cloud from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I have a collection of ContentDocumentIDs which are offered via a LWC, but I can't for the life of me access the related files. I've tried links, and, more recently, the NavigationMixin method which is supposed to give me a pop-up with a file preview. The proper ContentDocumentId gets logged in the console, but there is no further action.

Here is the JS file

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.getDocs';

import {NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation'
export default class KeyDocuments extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api accountId;
    docs = [];

    @wire(getRecords, { AccountId: "$accountId" }) 
    getResults(result) {
         if (result.data) {
            this.docs = result.data;
            console.log(this.docs.length);
        } else {
            console.log('Error msg', result.error);
        }
        
    }

    previewHandler(event){
        console.log(event.target.dataset.id);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview'
            },
            state : {
                selectedRecordId: event.target.dataset.id
            }
        })
    }

}
```

And FWIW the HTML

```
<template>
    
    <template for:each={docs} for:item="doc">
        
           <div class="tile-wrapper" key={doc.id}>
              <article class="slds-tile slds-media" >
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <span class="slds-icon_container" title="description of icon when needed">
                      <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-groups" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xlink:href={doc.iconLink}></use>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title={doc.name}>
                  <template lwc:if={doc.isFile}>
                    <span class="preview-link" onclick={previewHandler} data-id={doc.id}>{doc.name}</span>
                  </template>
                  <template lwc:else><a href={doc.link} target="_blank">{doc.name}</a>
                </template>
                </h3>
                <p class="slds-truncate">
                    {doc.category}
                </p>
                <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                    <template lwc:if={doc.description}>
                        <p class="slds-wrap" >
                            {doc.description}
                        </p>
                    </template>
                  
                  <p class="slds-truncate"><em>Updated {doc.mostRecentUpdate}</em></p>
                </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div> 
    </template>

</template>
```

The Apex Controller seems to be doing its job (as does the HTML).

Answer (score 2):

The way I read the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-page-reference-type.html), that isn't supported in Experience Cloud:

[image: named page container]

The only way I have every gotten this to work is the servlet method
e.g. append ContentVersionId to this URL:

```
itemurl = '[my Domain]/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?&rendition=SVGZ&versionId=[ContentId]
```

And then use img on the page:

```
<img src={itemurl}/>
```